# Null object reference for an interface/bundle

Tags: android, interface

I have a screen where I am collecting payment information. Here the user can either press the Back button to make changes to their purchase order in the ShopFragment or press the Submit button to go to the ConfirmationFragment. The Back button works fine but the Submit button results in this error:

```
06-27 01:07:38.321 14771-14771/com.shop.away E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shop.away, PID: 14771
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.shop.away.ui.PaymentFragment$OnPaymentSubmitListener.onPaymentSubmit(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
        at com.shop.away.ui.PaymentFragment$7.onSuccess(PaymentFragment.java:294)
        at com.shop.away.ui.PaymentFragment$7.onSuccess(PaymentFragment.java:289)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the code for **PaymentFragment**:

```
private OnPaymentSubmitListener paymentSubmitListener;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        paymentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);

btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                bundle.putBoolean("direction", false);
                paymentSubmitListener.onPaymentSubmit(bundle);
            }
        });

        btnPlaceOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getToken();
            }
        });
        return paymentView;
    }

private void getToken() {
// If token obtained successfully place order
}

private void placeOrder() {
if (orderPlaced.isSuccessful) {
bundle.putBoolean("direction", true);
                paymentSubmitListener.onPaymentSubmit(bundle);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Bundle bundle) {
        if (paymentSubmitListener != null) {
            paymentSubmitListener.onPaymentSubmit(bundle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        paymentContext = context;
        super.onAttach(paymentContext);
        if (context instanceof OnPaymentSubmitListener) {
            paymentSubmitListener = (OnPaymentSubmitListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        paymentSubmitListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnPaymentSubmitListener {
        void onPaymentSubmit(Bundle bundle);
    }
}
```

And in my **MainActivity** this is how I am handling the interface:

```
public void onPaymentSubmit(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("direction")) {
            Boolean direction = bundle.getBoolean("direction");
            if (!direction) {
                ShopFragment fragment = new ShopFragment();
                openFragment(bundle, fragment, direction);
            } else {
                ConfirmationFragment fragment = new ConfirmationFragment();
                openFragment(bundle, fragment, direction);
            }
        }
    }

private void openFragment(Bundle bundle, Fragment fragment, Boolean direction) {
// Open corresponding fragment using animation
}
```

The *PaymentFragment.java:294* refers specifically to this line here: paymentSubmitListener.onPaymentSubmit(bundle)

Comment: Where you are initializing 'paymentSubmitListener'

Comment: In onAttach. Is that now how you would initialize it?

Comment: where have you initalized paymentSubmitListener . do paymentSubmitListener=new          PaymentSubmitLisetner(params);

Comment: In getToken() method, Is there any chance for calling onDetach()?

Comment: No, there is no chance for calling onDetach(). I will try what Shivam suggested but it is weird that the Back button ALWAYS works without instantiation.

Comment: There is no need to instantiation. onAttach() is enough

Comment: Can you please comment the line 'paymentSubmitListener = null;' in onDetach() and check?

Comment: Instantiating the way Shivam suggested did not work. Will try commenting out null.

Comment: Tested with multiple instances. Commenting it out solves the problem but I need to clear the bundle (where would I do that?). Otherwise when the user goes back to the shopping section, previously entered data including already purchased items are still in the cart.

Comment: It means onDetach() method is called, Can you debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialise your listener in `onCreateView()` and add check

```
if(paymentSubmitListener != null)
```

before using it.

You getting null pointer because when coming back to previous fragment listener is not initialized because onAttach(Context context) called only when fragment is attached and when you are resuming to it is still attached, but listener field initialization is gone.

try moving this part

```
  if (context instanceof OnPaymentSubmitListener) {
            paymentSubmitListener = (OnPaymentSubmitListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
}
```

in to `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)`

By the way I would suggest to rethink your architecture because I don't think that it is good practice to use context as instance of listener. Better idea is make Fragment implement listener and use it as `this`.

Another think is that `Context` in fragment might be `null`.

Comment: But then what if it IS null. How do I instantiate it?

Comment: Agreed on the context part. I just created a separate instance of context and have been crash free for almost 24 hours and numerous tests. This way, I did not have to move the part you said I should consider moving. Also I have used the default constructor onButtonPressed. Thanks.

Comment: separate instance of context is also really bad idea. Don't use context as listener :)